# Lambda expressions order by and take issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a `IQueryable` list with `COLOURS` class type

```
IQueryable<COLOURS> renkler = dbcontext.colours.Select(s=>new COLOURS{ ....
```

I want to get random 2 rows, I am using this code block to do this:

```
renkler.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2);
```

I want 2 rows but sometimes its getting 3 rows or 5 rows:

[image]

`Take(2)` is not working - what's the problem?

I have noticed something when I check

```
var result = NewProducts().OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2);
int result_count = result.Count(); //This value is 2 :D
                                   //but ToList() result 5 :D
```

Entire MEthod:

```
public IQueryable<COLOURS> NewProducts() 
{
    DateTime simdi = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime simdi_30 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);

    var collection_products = DefaultColours()
                             .Where(w => ((w.add_date.Value >= simdi_30 && w.add_date.Value <= simdi) || w.is_new == true))
                             .OrderByDescending(o => o.add_date).Take(200)
                             .Select(s => new COLOURS
                             {
                                 colour_code = s.colour_code,
                                 model_code = s.products.model_code,
                                 sell_price = (decimal)s.sell_price,
                                 market_price = (decimal)s.market_price,
                                 is_new = (bool)s.is_new,
                                 product_id = (int)s.product_id,
                                 colour_name = s.name,
                                 product_name = s.products.name,
                                 description = s.products.description,
                                 img_path = s.product_images.FirstOrDefault(f => f.is_main == true).img_path,
                                 category_id = (int)s.category_relations.FirstOrDefault().category_id,
                                 display_order = (short)s.display_order,
                                 section_id = (int)s.products.section_id,
                                 stock_amount = s.pr_sizes.Where(w => w.is_active == true && w.quantity >= 0).Count() > 0 ? (int)s.pr_sizes.Where(w => w.is_active == true && w.quantity >= 0).Sum(s2 => s2.quantity) : 0,
                                                                      section_name = s.products.pr_sections.name,

                             });    
    return collection_products;
}

public IQueryable<COLOURS> RandomNewProducts(int n) 
{
    var result = NewProducts().OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(n);
    int result_count = result.Count(); //2
    //When I run this method it's getting 5 rows               
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well that may or may not influence the final query. Can you also show the query that is shown when hovering `result`? I would expect something like `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM (SELECT TOP 200 * FROM ...)`.

Comment: @theEmge: Lots of people are trying to help you here, and they're all saying "show me the code". They want the code so that they can reproduce your symptoms in order to figure out what's going wrong. Please stop putting partial code snippets in the comments - put the entirety of your code in the question, else you're just wasting everybody's time. If you can trim the code down to something simpler that still exhibits the problem, so much the better.

Comment: This looks like the Take() extension method on System.Linq.Enumerable, but is it really? Could it be another method of the same name on a different class? Please post all your code, including references / 'using' statements and the DefaultColours() method.

Comment: @Neil That could actually happen, I thought the compiler would warn you about the ambiguity but I just tested it and apparently it doesn't. OP should try replacing `renkler.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2);` with `System.Linq.Enumerable.Take<string>(renkler.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()), 2);` to be sure.

Comment: Having the implementation of `DefaultColours()` would be nice as well, since it's an IQueryable. -- @Neil: its the `Queryable.Take()`-extension, not `Enumerable.Take()`.

Comment: Are you calling RandomNewProducts asynchronously?

Comment: Take(n) - returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence. **Not random.**

Comment: @parachutingturtle If you use the enumerable version then you're pulling down *the entire database table* when you only need two rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This may be no solution to you but it's hard to format comments with multiline code and images.*

I'm pretty sure that this is an issue with your data provider. Maybe this component does not implement `Take()` the way it should.

I tried to rebuild your constellation but instead of any `IQueryable` provider I built a `List<>` with 500 objects and called `AsQueryable()` on it to satisfy the method signature.

```
    public static IQueryable<COLOURS> DefaultColours()
    {
        const int COUNT = 500;

        List<COLOURS> x = new List<COLOURS>();

        var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * (int)(COUNT / 2));

        // add 500 date values, and use the date and any random bool value
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
            x.Add(new COLOURS() { add_date = startDate.AddDays(i), is_new = i % 3 == 0 });

        return x.AsQueryable();
    }
```

But when I do this, the `Take()` method is always returning two (different) items each time - just as anyone would expect:

[image: debugger view]

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the o => Guid.NewGuid() lambda.

The sorting algorithm requires a unique key that is tied to each element.  Calling Guid.NewGuid() means that any given element could have multiple keys associated with it depending on when it gets called.  Linq attempts to be opportunistic in how it operates on sets, so this could cause e.g. the lowest two elements to suddenly no longer be the lowest two elements during the sorting operation.

Consider trying to sort a list of random integers where those integers are randomly changing every time the sorting algorithm tries to retrieve them.  The only way this would work is if the sorting algorithm provides a guarantee to call the key function once and only once for every element.

The documentation on the OrderBy does not say whether the sorting algorithm is allowed to call the key function more than once for each element, so it is best to assume the worst case unless you can prove otherwise.

As a (hopefully) simple way to test this, if you can temporarily include the random key as a persistent element of your COLOUR object so the order does not change during the sort, the .Take() should begin working exactly as intended.

Also, Guid.NewGuid() is not fast, so turning that temporary test into a permanent solution that uses a bit more memory for each object could improve the speed of your code as well.